# How to know what was clicked in two identical items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am having a problem toggling some content that was clicked.The two items are identical and once i click one item,the other item that was not clicked toggles too.Is there a technique i can use to identify what was clicked so that the clicked item can toggle and the other is unaffected?.

Here is the example in jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dNt9e/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated your Fiddle, please check here - http://jsfiddle.net/57vsn/4/

Basically what's changed is the following:

```
if($('.toggleContent', $(this).parent()).is(':visible')){
    $('.toggleContent', $(this).parent()).hide("slow");
    $('.green', $(this).parent()).val("+");
} else {
    $('.toggleContent', $(this).parent()).show("slow");
    $('.green', $(this).parent()).val("-");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(function(){
    $('.togglenav').click(function(e){  
        if($(this).closest('.toggleContainer').find(".toggleContent").is(':visible'){
            $(this).closest('.toggleContainer').find(".toggleContent").hide("slow");
            $('.green',this).val("+");
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.toggleContainer').find(".toggleContent").show("slow");
            $('.green',this).val("-");
        }

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dNt9e/2/

Answer (score 0):

give your elements different ids and then for both ids write two different functions of toggle that will be called on click event like `jQuery(#id1).click(function() {
 // Your code to toggle
})` and same for other ellement

Comment: Have different ids for the both items is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the toggle on `$(this)` in the event.

$(this) means the element which fire the event.